# Ubuntu 18.04 with deprecated Hardware Enablement Stacks

Tags: 18.04, hardware-enablement-stack

I have upgraded to 18.04 couple of weeks ago and today found out my currently installed HWE is deprecated.

`hwe-support-status --show-all-unsupported` output is:

```
linux-image-3.19.0-59-generic libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid 
linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid 
linux-image-extra-3.19.0-58-generic xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid 
xserver-xorg-lts-vivid linux-image-extra-3.19.0-59-generic 
linux-image-3.19.0-58-generic xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid
```

and `hwe-support-status --show-replacements` output is:

```
linux-generic-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial
```

But when I try to install these packages, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-lts-xenial
E: Unable to locate package libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-lts-xenial
```

Comment: Why do you want to install these?, makes no sense..

Comment: @doug aren't they supported packages? Or they forgot to update it in 18.04?

Comment: 18.04 will get it's own HWE path starting next year around Feb. (or earlier with the 'edge' meta package). The ones you've listed have no use in 18.04. See here for 18.04 rolling release roadmap, ect. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack & here for general info https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: @doug So I should stick to the old ones until next year? Still doesn't make sense to be with 14.04 packages although there are newer ones shipped with 16.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've got an  HWE (hardware enablement) stack left over from 14.04, [which has been deprecated for a long time now](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL#What_is_HWE.3F). It's common for upgrades to leave old packages installed. I would recommend uninstalling them:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-3.19.0-59-generic libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid linux-image-extra-3.19.0-58-generic xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid linux-image-extra-3.19.0-59-generic linux-image-3.19.0-58-generic xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid
```

I'd also run these commands just to make sure you don't have any other 14.04 HWE packages installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | egrep "utopic|vivid|wily|xenial"
dpkg --get-selections | egrep "linux-.+-(3\.16|3\.19|4\.2|4\.4)"
```

If you do, you can uninstall them with these commands:

```
sudo apt purge `dpkg --get-selections | egrep "utopic|vivid|wily|xenial" | awk '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' '`
sudo apt purge `dpkg --get-selections | egrep "linux-.+-(3\.16|3\.19|4\.2|4\.4)" | awk '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' '`
```